# “The same as” usage in a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

When flying drone, I can perform acrobatic maneuvers with heavier drone easily. Small drones are too light to keep the positions sometimes. When I fly indoors:

> I can play the same tricks with this tiny drone as the big one.

Is there any grammar error of the usage of “the same as”? How can I say it in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of "the same" is fine. However, your use of "as the big one" could be considered ambiguous. It might mean:

> I can play the same tricks with this tiny drone as [[I can play with]] the big one.

Or:

> I can play the same tricks with this tiny drone as the big one [[can play with this tiny drone]].

Of course, the second sentence doesn't really make sense, so most readers should be able to tell that you mean the first. However, it is very easy to make the sentence 100% clear:

> I can play the same tricks with this tiny drone as with the big one.

Comment: Haha, Thank you, the “with” makes it perfect.